# Who should know about the other?

Tags: c++, oop

I always run into confusion with who should know about the other.

for example:

`Circle.Draw(&canvas)` or `Canvas.Draw(&circle)`

or  `Draw(&canvas, &circle)`

`EmployeeVector.Save(&file)`   or  `File.Save(&employee_vector)`

or even still

```
  void operator() (Employee e) { Save( e.Serialize();}
  for_each(employees.begin(), employees.end(),File)
```

I think I end up "abstracting" too much where I have all kinds of adapters so nobody knows about anybody.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on who has the expertise.

If the only thing you can draw are circles, then of course you could just put that in `Canvas` and be on your way. If `Canvas` has a method to draw generic `Shape`s, then it falls on the various subclasses of `Shape` to draw themselves. For instance, a circle surely knows how to draw itself on a canvas. I doubt a canvas knows natively how to draw a circle, unless you hardcode the functionality, which kinda kills the whole idea of polymorphism.

For the same reasons, a vector would probably know how to save itself to a file, but I doubt a file knows what to do with a vector. But a vector can contain a variety of things, so it should delegate most of the work to its actual elements. So the `for_each` idea is probably the best.

Comment: What if the canvas were to change? Than you would have to change circle code instead of just canvas code.

Comment: @Joe You would have to change the code anyway. If you change the canvas, you either have to modify a bunch of methods in `Canvas`, or modify a method in each shape class. Either way, it makes more sense to modify code related to a circle in the `Circle` class than to do it in the `Canvas` class. Also, why would the canvas change? Its interface would probably have to stay the change to avoid breaking callers.

Comment: @Joe: If there is a chance that the canvas might change, employ polymorphism. Either dynamic (virtual functions), or static (templates) and have them all satisfy the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

Like most design questions, the answer is, it depends.  :-)

Is it meaningful for something to know how to draw itself? possibly.   It's also equally possibly that something else knows how to draw it. If the object is a graphical entity, it probably should know how to draw itself.

As for things like saving, again, it depends... it can be good for things to know how to serialize themselves to an abstraction like a stream, but also, sometimes, it's better not to couple entities to such trivial matters like serialization....

Answer (score 0):

For classes that you are creating, you usually make them do work involving themselves. A `Circle` will draw itself onto a `Canvas`, so will a `Rectangle`. That way, if they are all subclasses of `Shape`, they can draw themselves through a `Shape` interface. It is the same for saving. This is extensible -- you do not need to guess all the possible shapes when designing the `Canvas` class.

For the "it depends" cases, for me, it usually involves utility methods for classes already defined by some library. For example, save/load commonly used STL data structures like map, set, vector, etc; via  a `File` utility class with `static` methods.